# longhorn and ebs and autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, storage, amazon-ebs, longhorn

We use longhornand EBS-aws on our kubernetes clusters. but I would to active cluster-autoscaler for our instances ec2.

If an ec2 instance is down auto scaling create a new instance with an empty ebs and longhorn recreate a volume with replicas.

Is it possible to reuse an old ebs instance instead to create a new ebs?

For example with portwork it's possible.

https://portworx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/asg-slides.pdf

I would like separate compute to storage.

Comment: In essence yes. EBS is seperate from the instance so you can detach and attach an EBS any time. For EBS created with instance, there is a flag "DeleteOnTermination" wheter do delete or keep the EBS after termination.

Comment: I would like to automatically attach this ebs which no longer has ec2 instances

Comment: In detail requires an answer(no time).
a) Kubernetes Volumes and types. b) Longhorn in this scenario. c) What is a replica. d) What happens in case corrupted/outdated disk? Additional ebs in the user section with a call  aws ec2 attach-volume. e) Termination protection.
f) Livecycle hooks
g) see also recover: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/automatic-recovery-ec2-cloudwatch/ If I find time I can write it but I can only give you the bulletpoints that may help you.